# PSQL Shell nor my jdbc-url can find my Docker container databases on application boot up

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, psql

I am attempting to follow along a SpringBoot tutorial
[here](https://youtu.be/vtPkZShrvXQ)

and the final act is using a .yml file to bridge my logic code to a containerized database. On start up, the application does not find my containerized database at

**jdbc-url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/demodb**

and I get this error

**FATAL: database "demodb" does not exist**

To create database "demodb" with the psql shell was the only way to avoid this error but,

I want to be able to use the container's database, and I believed that the psql shell would have visibility to what was created inside my container.
[The screenshot here proves otherwise (Left is the shell). (Right is the container)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2UCN.png)

All logins (for container and the shell) are identical yet entering psql -U postgres in the command prompt leads to my localhost psql.

When I use \conninfo, my shell's databases are connected to "localhost" (address "::1") at port "5432" while the container databases are connected via socket in "/var/run/postgresql" at port "5432".

Changing my jdbc to **jdbc-url: jdbc:postgresql://var/run/postgresql:5432/demodb** did not work aswell.

Is it because I have two different psqls on my computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an answer to my own question, those who want to have a jdbc url connecting to a docker container database, one must make sure to stop any Postgresql 12 service.

Initially, my connection was refused at my container IP but I could connect via terminal. My postgres dbms was in localhost too.